# Angular, how to make consecutive, dependent http get requests

Tags: javascript, angular, http, get, observable

I'd like to execute one http get request after another has completed. The endpoint URL for the second request will need to depend on the first request.

I've tried nesting the requests with something like this in Angular:

```
this.http.get(endpoint1).subscribe(
   success => {
      this.http.get(endpoint2 + success).subscribe(
         anotherSuccess => console.log('hello stackoverflow!')
      );
   }
);
```

First question here on stackoverflow, please let me know if I should provide more detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011375/5781575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here you can find how to do that](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs), you have various options:

with subscribe:

```js
this.http.get('/api/people/1').subscribe(character => {
  this.http.get(character.homeworld).subscribe(homeworld => {
    character.homeworld = homeworld;
    this.loadedCharacter = character;
  });
});
```

with mergeMap

```js
this.homeworld = this.http
  .get('/api/people/1')
  .pipe(mergeMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld)));
```

There is a version with forkJoin but isn't explicit compared with subscribe and mergeMap.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try using `ngrx` (redux) triggering the second request depending on a `success` action.

The flow should be something like this: dispatch an action from a component -> call the first request -> the request triggers a success action -> success effect triggers the second request with a payload from the previous request.

[image]

[Read the docs here](https://ngrx.io/docs)